# Junit assert on uninitialized char

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to assert on uninitialized char in Junit4-eclipse and get unexpected result:

`x` field is declared as `private char x`, while in some cases I am using the setter,

```
public void setX(char x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

in Junit I am trying to assert on uninitialize cases for x and assert:
`assertNull(transactionContext.getX());`

the error is: 
`java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<`

1. How can I assert on uninitialize char field without initialize him with 0? 0 is the default value for char in java as I understand.

2.It's better to use `assertEquals` in that case?

Comment: have you tried by initializing it with null?

Comment: you can initialize char with null, only Character can be set to null... "null" for char is `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class abc {
    private char a;
    public char getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(char a) {
        this.a = a;
    }   
}
```

PFB the test code for above class:

```
    public class tester {   
        @Test
        public void test() throws Exception{
        abc a = new abc();
        Assert.assertEquals((int)a.getA(), 0);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've found it better asserting this way than '\u0000'

Answer (score 1):

By default primitive character is initialized as '\u0000' and not as null, so you might want to check something like:

```
assertEquals(transactionContext.getX(), '\u0000');
```

By default, In Java all the objects (including array like `int[]`) are initialized to null by default.

Wrapper `Character` class would be initialized to `null` by default.